# Solaris 10 - split with numeric suffix

Tags: linux, unix, solaris

I need to split file with numeric suffix in Solaris 10. Example:-

```
bash-3.2# more testfile_split.txt
this is line 1
this is line 2
```

I use **split -l 1 testfile_split.txt testfile_split_** . This will output,

```
testfile_split_aa
testfile_split_ab
```

-d option doesn't seem to work on Solaris 10.

Comment: Is GNU `split` installed?  Perhaps in `/usr/sfw/bin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a small custom script:

```
awk '{ print > "testfile_split_"i++ }' testfile_split.txt
```

When you want a suffix with leading zeroes, try

```
awk '{ out=sprintf ("testfile_split_%04d", i++); print > out }' testfile_split.txt
```